# How can I prevent android back button from closing the app only when you are at the base last window in a navigation stack in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a custom bottom navigation system using the CupertinoTabBar and its working decently well, but I've come across a problem with the backbitten on Android.

When I have windows open, back button properly closes my screens (navigates to the previous screen) but when I'm at the very last screen, if you press back the whole app will close.

I'd like to try to prevent this

Is there a good way for me to detect when I am at my base window and prevent this in the `WillPopScope` area?

Heres my bottom navigation bar code as it stands

```
class MarkBottomNav2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MarkBottomNav2> createState() => _MarkBottomNavState2();
}

class _MarkBottomNavState2 extends State<MarkBottomNav2> {

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> firstTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> secondTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> thirdTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> fourthTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> fifthTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  late CupertinoTabController tabController;
  int index = 0;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    tabController = CupertinoTabController(initialIndex: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //making a list of the keys
    final listOfKeys = [
      firstTabNavKey,
      secondTabNavKey,
      thirdTabNavKey,
      fourthTabNavKey,
      fifthTabNavKey,
    ];

    List homeScreenList = [
      NewsArea(),
      Area2(),
      Area3(),
      Area4(),
      Area5()
    ];
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          
          return !await listOfKeys[tabController.index].currentState!.maybePop();
        },
        child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
          controller: tabController, //set tabController here

          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            items: [
              ///this is where we are setting aur bottom ICONS
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(FontAwesome5.newspaper),
                label: 'News',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted), label: 'Area 2'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline_outlined), label: 'Area 3'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.alternate_email), label: 'Area 4'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz), label: 'Area 5'),
            ],
            activeColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 70, 128, 1),
            inactiveColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 70, 128, 0.3),
            iconSize:20,
            // currentIndex: pageIndex,
          ),
          tabBuilder: (
              context,
              index,
              ) {
            return CupertinoTabView(
              navigatorKey: listOfKeys[
              index], //set navigatorKey here which was initialized before
              builder: (context) {
                return homeScreenList[index];
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      );



  }


}
```

Comment: try to determine by using canPop

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code and use this first page where from page exit

```
DateTime currentBackPressTime;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    ...
    body: WillPopScope(child: getBody(), onWillPop: onWillPop),
  );
}

Future<bool> onWillPop() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null || 
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: exit_warning);
      return Future.value(false);
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  }
```